# Existance of monomial ordering

Tags: monomial-order

Let $k$ be a field and let $f\in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ be a polynomial.
Write $$f = \sum_\alpha \underline{X}^{\underline{\alpha}}\qquad  \underline{X}^{\underline{\alpha}} \text{ is a monomial in }X_1,\ldots,X_n. $$
For every $\alpha$ appearing above, does there exists a [monomial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order), such that $\mathrm{LM}(f) = \underline{X}^{\underline{\alpha}}$? ($\mathrm{LM}$ stands for leading monomial).

-- Mike

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $f(X)=1+X+X^2$. If you want $X$ to be the single leading monomial, you need

$$X > 1\quad\text{and}\quad X> X^2.$$

But $X> 1\Rightarrow X\cdot X> X\cdot 1\Rightarrow X^2> X$.

Comment: Thanks @Winter. Now with your example, my own question looks quite stupid... However I am still wondering if it is possible characterize / put some condition on $f$, so that I can have a monomial ordering for every term!

Comment: @MikeV.D.C. This is a very interesting question. After some initial thought on the problem I concluded that it is non-trivial and I recommend you to post another question to ask this. This question here however is sufficiently answered (assuming you are satisfied with my answer to the original question). When/if you start another post, let me know, I would love to participate.